# Comparing a string to values in an array to return true or false

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I have this code:

```
$specific_discount_dates = get_field('specific_discount_dates', 'options');

$specific_discount_dates_array = array();
if (have_rows('specific_discount_dates', 'options')) {
while ( have_rows( 'specific_discount_dates', 'options') ) : the_row();
    $other_discount_dates   = get_sub_field('other_discount_date');
    $date_obj               = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $other_discount_dates);
    $formatted_date         = date_format($date_obj, 'd-m-Y');
    array_push($specific_discount_dates_array, $formatted_date);
endwhile;
}

if (in_array($end_date, $specific_discount_dates_array)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

If I echo `$end_date` I get this: `28-04-2023`

If I `print_r($specific_discount_dates_array)` I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 24-04-2023
    [1] => 30-04-2023
)
```

Yet for some reason the condition always returns true, even though 28-04-2023 does not match any of the strings in the array.

What am I missing?

Comment: Upgrade to PHP 8 you will get a false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in_array` function performs a non-strict comparison by default, that's why it is returning `true`.

Use the third parameter in the `in_array` function to perform a strict comparison.

```
if (in_array($end_date, $specific_discount_dates_array, true)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```